# cannot find Gradle Tasks in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am a beginner level programmer. What I need is the sha-1 key of my project, but the problem is that my gradle button is not showing any tasks. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1gEJ.jpg). If I use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSPIj.jpg) gradle build tasks, it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOELa.jpg). Please tell me what can I do to get my sha-1 key?

Comment: can you add more details to this question?

Comment: what more details you want? You tell and i will give you

Comment: You have added 'here' and 'it shows this' in the question without linking anything or adding anything to support it. How can anyone who see the question know what that actually means?

Comment: oh sry, the hyperlink is not working, let me make it work

Comment: Please check now

Comment: what is the android studio version

Comment: 4.2.1 is my current version of android studio

Comment: `keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v`
run this from the android studio terminal

Comment: `Gradle Projects > app > Tasks > android > signingReports` is this path not available to you?

Comment: No, the path is not available to me, i have path Compass Food Life > app > Dependencies

Comment: Gradle task list is large and slow to populate in Android projects. This feature by default is disabled for performance reasons. You can re-enable it in: `Settings | Experimental | Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync`

Comment: If I run it in the terminal it shows that keytool is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or a batch file. Or if I run it in the gradle command, it shows 

`
Task 'keytool' not found in root project 'Compass Food Life'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'keytool' not found in root project 'Compass Food Life'.`

The exception was too long, I cant show it the whole

Comment: And my Do not build gradle task list during gradle sync is on by default, if I turn it off, it shows reset settings button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232623/discussion-between-bijin-abraham-and-aksha-sharma).